# Docker build with buildx keeps rebuilding without using cache

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker build doesn't use cache, when I rerun the docker build command:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64,linux/arm64/v8 -t testing/image_1:latest -f jetson.Dockerfile . --push
```

This is the dockerfile in question:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-pytorch:r35.2.1-pth2.0-py3
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    libxrender-dev \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    pciutils && \
    apt-get clean


COPY requirements_jetson.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements_jetson.txt

# Clean CV2
RUN rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2 \
 && rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2
RUN python3 -m pip uninstall opencv-python -y \
 && python3 -m pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python -y
RUN python3 -m pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64

EXPOSE 8000

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE VisualInspectionService.settings
ENV YOLO_VERBOSE=False OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh

COPY paddleocr/pre_models/ch_ppocr_mobile_v2.0_cls_infer.tar /root/.paddleocr/whl/det/en/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar
COPY paddleocr/pre_models/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar /root/.paddleocr/whl/det/en/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer/en_PP-OCRv3_det_infer.tar
COPY paddleocr/pre_models/en_PP-OCRv4_rec_infer.tar /root/.paddleocr/whl/rec/en/en_PP-OCRv4_rec_infer/en_PP-OCRv4_rec_infer.tar

ADD . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Why is this happening? I tried modifying the docker file but nothing helped.